# Use transient when importing to another module

Tags: python, tkinter

Well, here turning to the forum for help. I have a routine in which I import module dos.py, and I need module dos.py (toplevel) to always be in front of my main screen uno.py. I cannot get transient to work, previously I had no problems because I did not need the screen that is always present, but now I need my screen dos.py to be always ahead of one.py.

Here I have the problem, I do not apply transient when it comes to importing modules

I leave the routine very short to understand how transient is handled, thank you.

```
# uno.py

  import tkinter as tk 
  class PRUEBA:
      def __init__(self):

          ventana_principal = tk.Tk()        
          ventana_principal.geometry ("600x600") 
          ventana_principal.config (bg="blue") 
          ventana_principal.title ("PANTALLA PRINCIPAL") 

          def importar():
    
              from dos import toplevel
              toplevel()
          boton = tk.Button (ventana_principal , text = "boton" , command = importar)
          boton.pack ( )

          ventana_principal.mainloop()  
  PRUEBAS = PRUEBA ()
```

******module dos.py****

```
 #dos.py

 import tkinter as tk 

 class toplevel:
     def __init__(self):

        secundario = tk.Toplevel ()       
        secundario.geometry ("150x40+190+100")        
        secundario.resizable(0,0)
        secundario.transient(self.master)  """ Here I have the problem not to apply transient
                                          when it comes to importing modules """
```

sorry

Comment: What is `TKI_Principal`? Should it be `secundario` instead?

Comment: Sorry is secundario

Answer (score 0):

Your code will raise exception:

> AttributeError: 'toplevel' object has no attribute 'master'

The line `secundario.transient(self.master)` should be `secundario.transient(secundario.master)` instead.

But the instance of `toplevel` is useless because you cannot access `secundario` later as it is a local variable.

Suggest to make `toplevel` inherit from `tk.Toplevel`:

```
class toplevel(tk.Toplevel):
     def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kw)
        self.geometry("150x40+190+100")        
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        self.transient(parent)
```

And then create it like:

```
top = toplevel(ventana_principal)
```

Comment: Please accept the answer if it helps as it is used in your another question [how-to-use-destroy-in-these-cases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63477254/how-to-use-destroy-in-these-cases)