# how to use destroy in these cases

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

ran into another problem when handling modules. I can't get "destroy" to work.
I want to open with a button and close with another button the toplevel window.

Here is a little code to apply destroy

```
# module uno.py

import tkinter as tk 
class PRUEBA:
    def __init__(*args):
    
        ventana_principal = tk.Tk()        
        ventana_principal.geometry ("600x600") 
        ventana_principal.config (bg="blue") 
        ventana_principal.title ("PANTALLA PRINCIPAL") 
    
        def importar():
        
            from dos import toplevel
            top = toplevel(ventana_principal)  

        boton = tk.Button (ventana_principal , text = "open" , command = importar)
        boton.pack ( )  
        boton1 = tk.Button (ventana_principal , text = "close" , command = top.destroy) #does not work destroy
        boton1.pack ( )
    
        ventana_principal.mainloop()  
PRUEBAS = PRUEBA ()

#module dos.py

import tkinter as tk 

class toplevel(tk.Toplevel):
     def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kw):
        super().__init__(parent, *args, **kw)
        self.geometry("150x40+190+100")        
        self.resizable(0, 0)
        self.transient(parent)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is because `top` is a local variable inside `importar()` function.

Use instance variable `self.top` instead:

```
class PRUEBA:
    def __init__(self, *args):
    
        ventana_principal = tk.Tk()        
        ventana_principal.geometry("600x600") 
        ventana_principal.config(bg="blue") 
        ventana_principal.title("PANTALLA PRINCIPAL") 
    
        def importar():
            from dos import toplevel
            self.top = toplevel(ventana_principal)  

        boton = tk.Button(ventana_principal, text="open", command=importar)
        boton.pack()  
        boton1 = tk.Button(ventana_principal, text="close", command=lambda: self.top.destroy())
        boton1.pack()
```

---

Note that you need to cater the situation where `open` button is clicked more than once before `close` button is clicked.  Then there will be two or more `toplevel` windows and `close` button can only close the last open window.

Also you cannot click `close` button before `open` button.